# Rewrite log says it gets applied... but it is not

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, debian

Im on the end with my knowledge, same for my IT admin.

We setup a new Debian GNU/Linux 8 server
Installed apache and all.. 
ALL works Except the darn rules. Strange thing is. The rewrite rule log says they are working but the browser from which we open the url dous not.

Here is the complete log from when i open xxx.xxx.xxx/bla

```
[Fri Dec 16 03:37:04.064896 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1850] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xxx.xxx.xxx:22260] xxx.xxx.xxx - - [sccatdev.office.dig/sid#7f35b0df5d20][rid#7f35b0d3c0a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /bla/
[Fri Dec 16 03:37:04.064936 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1850] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xxx.xxx.xxx:22260] xxx.xxx.xxx - - [sccatdev.office.dig/sid#7f35b0df5d20][rid#7f35b0d3c0a0/initial] applying pattern '^/deploy/ajax/(.+)/(\\w+)/(\\w+?)$' to uri '/bla/'
[Fri Dec 16 03:37:04.064944 2016] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 1850] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xxx.xxx.xxx:22260] xxx.xxx.xxx - - [sccatdev.office.dig/sid#7f35b0df5d20][rid#7f35b0d3c0a0/initial] applying pattern '^/bla/$' to uri '/bla/'
[Fri Dec 16 03:37:04.064950 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1850] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xxx.xxx.xxx:22260] xxx.xxx.xxx - - [sccatdev.office.dig/sid#7f35b0df5d20][rid#7f35b0d3c0a0/initial] rewrite '/bla/' -> '/deploy/main.phtml'
[Fri Dec 16 03:37:04.065044 2016] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1850] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xxx.xxx.xxx:22260] xxx.xxx.xxx - - [sccatdev.office.dig/sid#7f35b0df5d20][rid#7f35b0d3c0a0/initial] local path result: /deploy/main.phtml
[Fri Dec 16 03:37:04.065062 2016] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1850] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xxx.xxx.xxx:22260] xxx.xxx.xxx - - [sccatdev.office.dig/sid#7f35b0df5d20][rid#7f35b0d3c0a0/initial] go-ahead with /deploy/main.phtml [OK]
```

To clerify, i emptied the logs. and opend exacly 1 time the page i got a 404, but logs say it passed the main.phtml trough.. so... wtf?

For testing i made a simple bla rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName xxxx.xxx.xxx

        ServerAdmin webmaster@dig.at
        DocumentRoot /data1/www/xxxx.xxx.xx/htdocs
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.phtml index.php
        ErrorLog /data1/www/xxxx.xxx.xx/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /data1/www/xxxx.xxx.xx/logs/access.log combined
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8

        #ajax handler for
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule   ^/deploy/ajax/(.+)/(\w+)/(\w+?)$       /deploy/ajax/handler.php?path=$1&class=$2&method=$3 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule  ^/bla$ /deploy/main.phtml


</VirtualHost>
```

yess mod rewrite ext is on... yes we traced the call in the error log... the log is given above... we tried all what google spited out.

Server is a fresh install of:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:        8.6
Codename:       jessie
```

Comment: `http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/deploy/main.phtml` when entered directly in browser address bar works OK?

Comment: yes works perfectly fine. Only problem is the rewrite rule.

Comment: Is there perhaps `.htaccess` in `/data1/www/xxxx.xxx.xx/htdocs`? Also, are there any Rewrite directives in global `http.conf`?

Comment: Ah, most probably you have `/deploy` at the root of your file system?